# Binding dynamic form values with vue.js

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I've built a dynamic set of form inputs using `vue.js`, where the form inputs are generated from an external list of inputs.

My problem is that I don't see how I can bind the input values back to the vue model, so that the vue instance can access / interact with the form values.

I've created a basic fiddle to give you the idea here: https://jsfiddle.net/gzprj5ef/

Is it possible to update the vue instance with the form values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove double brackets when you are using `v-model`.

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzprj5ef/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-model="input.value", and you can take a result in variable 'inputs'.